# Does this inequality hold? $\Big| \frac{n-1+\exp(i\pi p)}{n}\Big|^{1/p}<1.$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $p\in (-1,1)\setminus \{ 0\}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Does the following inequality hold? $$\Big| \frac{n-1+\exp(i\pi p)}{n}\Big|^{1/p}<1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $p\in(0,1)$. Your inequality is equivalent to
$$ |n-1+\cos(p\pi)+i\sin(p\pi)|<n\tag1$$
or
$$ (n-1+\cos(p\pi))^2+\sin^2(p\pi)<n^2 $$
But
$$ (n-1)^2+2(n-1)\cos(p\pi)-n^2=-2(n-1)[1-\cos(p\pi)]-1<0 $$
which is true. So (1) holds.

Another way: Using $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$, one has
$$ |n-1+\exp(ip\pi)|\le |n-1|+|\exp(ip\pi)|=n. $$
The equal sign holds iff $n-1=k\exp(ip\pi)$ for some $k>0$. Clearly such $k>0$ does not exist. So one must have the $<$ sign or
$$ |n-1+\exp(ip\pi)|<n. $$

If $p\in(-1,0)$, the inequality doesn't hold. For example, let $n=3,p=-0.9$, then
$$\Big| \frac{n-1+\exp(i\pi p)}{n}\Big|^{1/p}=2.7788043437691594>1. $$
For $p\in(-1,0)$, the equality should be
$$\Big| \frac{n-1+\exp(i\pi p)}{n}\Big|^{1/p}>1. $$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for your help and nice answers.

Comment: @xpaul To reach $(1)$, did you apply the $p$-th power both sides to the initial statement? Because $p\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$, and for $p\in(-1,0)$ the $p$-th power $t^p$ is decreasing for $t \ge 0$. So the inequality sign should be reversed. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ZaWarudo, you are right. I supposed $p>0$. If $p<0$, the situation is different. Thanks.